# Understanding Dirichlet regularization in Sum

Tags: summation

I've tried to calculate few classic sums using Dirichlet regularization:

```
Sum[n, {n, 1, ∞}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
Sum[n^2, {n, 1, ∞}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
```

I get expected results: `-1/12` and `0`.

But when I start sum from the `0`, I notice an interesting pattern:

$$
\sum_0^\infty n^k - \sum_1^\infty n^k = (-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k + 1}
$$

I'm having trouble understanding this. Is this some misuse of Dirichlet regularization in *Mathematica*, or some interesting (or not) thing in the math itself?

Comment: You might want to read this [Wolfram Blog article](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/08/06/the-abcd-of-divergent-series/).

Comment: Actually, after this article I tried this. I just can't understand what method *Mathematica* use; if we add zero, the Maclaurin series shouldn't change, but the answer is different.

Comment: Dirichlet regularization is not *stable*. What that means is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \neq a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n$, where the sums here are Dirichlet regularized. See https://brilliant.org/wiki/sums-of-divergent-series/#dirichlet-series-regularization

Comment: This bug has been fixed since then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Dirichlet series do not make sense when the index starts at zero, to Zeta-regularize $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n),$ Mathematica reasonably replaces it with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n-1),$ so you are saying that 
$$\sum_{l=0}^{k-1} (-1)^l S_l \binom{k}{l} = (-1)^{k+1}/(k+1),$$
where $S_l$ is the regularized sum of $n^l,$ which is interesting, but is a mathematical (rather than a Mathematica) fact.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more about $S_l$? And that's a binomial coefficient, right?

Comment: $S_l = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^l$ (Dirichlet-regularized). And yes, a binomial coefficient.

Comment: So, $S_l = -1/12$? It didn't calculates well: `Sum[-(1/12) Binomial[k, l], {l, 1, k}] /. {k -> 3}`, am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I was typing in a hurry, look at the corrected formula (you are comparing $(n-1)^k$ with $n^k,$ so you can check this yourself...)

Comment: Now's that's will equal to $(-1)^k S_l$. Maybe you missed something else?

Comment: Sigh. $n^k - (n-1)^k = -\sum_{l=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{l} n^l.$ Now, regularize term-by-term.