# Weird sum regularization?

Tags: summation

I noticed some weird behavior in `"Dirichlet"` regularization of infinite sums.
Let us first compute

```
 Sum[i, {i, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
```

Sure enough, the answer is

> -1/12

Which can be explained by what the regularization actually does. The [reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Regularization.html) page states that $\lim_{s\to0}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{i}{i^s}=\lim_{s\to0}\zeta(-1+s)=\zeta(-1)=-1/12$ is what is being computed in this case. So far there are no problems. Let us now shift the summation index down by an integer

```
Sum[i, {i, 0, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
```

Naively, one would not expect the result to change, since adding zero to a sum should do nothing. Even in the regularized version no problems are expected, since we are interested in the $|s|<1$ case. Yet for some reason the result changes to

> 5/12

Is this a bug? Or maybe the routine relies on some mathematics that I missed? Would be great if someone could clarify this. Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: This bug has been fixed in version 12

Answer (score 5):

The suggested answer to a similar question asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59425/understanding-dirichlet-regularization-in-sum) just explains how adding a zero causes a formal overall shift by an integer in the summation range, which causes the Dirichlet regularization to become ambiguous. Indeed, it is not a problem with Mathematica but with the regularization technique. Luckily, [this](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/08/06/the-abcd-of-divergent-series/) blog entry gives a much sturdier regularization technique, using which we get

```
SeriesCoefficient[Sum[i Exp[-q i], {i, 1, Infinity}], {q, 0, 0}]
```

with result

> -1/12

And

```
SeriesCoefficient[Sum[i Exp[-q i], {i, 0, Infinity}], {q, 0, 0}]
```

with result

> -1/12

in both cases, whether a zero in the summation is included or not. The consensus is:

> Avoid `"Dirichlet"` regularization.

Comment: This was actually a problem in Mathematica. It has been fixed in version 12